# Has optaplanners toList ConstraintCollector a bug?

Tags: optaplanner

When using toList() ConstraintCollector in optaplanner 8.1 like:

```java
factory.from(Lesson.class)
          .groupBy(Lesson::getCourse, ConstraintCollectors.toList()).penalize(...);
```

I run into:

```
Exception executing consequence for rule "foo" in model: java.lang.ClassCastException: class model.Lesson cannot be cast to class java.util.List (model.Lesson is in unnamed module of loader 'app'; java.util.List is in module java.base of loader 'bootstrap')
    at org.drools.core.runtime.rule.impl.DefaultConsequenceExceptionHandler.handleException(DefaultConsequenceExceptionHandler.java:39)
```

**Question: Is this a optaplanner bug, or is my code wrong?**

---

The most simple complete reproducer I find is:

```java
@PlanningSolution
public class OptaplannerIssue2 implements ConstraintProvider {

  @Override
  public Constraint[] defineConstraints(ConstraintFactory factory) {
    return new Constraint[] {factory.from(IssueEntity.class)
        .groupBy(IssueEntity::getValue, ConstraintCollectors.toList())
        .penalize("x", HardSoftScore.ofHard(1), (entity, enityList) -> 2)};
  }

  @PlanningScore
  private HardSoftScore score = HardSoftScore.ZERO;

  @PlanningEntityCollectionProperty
  private final List<IssueEntity> entities = new ArrayList<IssueEntity>();

  public List<IssueEntity> getEntities() {
    return entities;
  }

  @ValueRangeProvider(id = "valueRange")
  public CountableValueRange<Integer> getValueRange() {
    return ValueRangeFactory.createIntValueRange(0, 4);
  }

  public static void main() {
    // create Entity
    OptaplannerIssue2 issue = new OptaplannerIssue2();
    IssueEntity e1 = new IssueEntity();
    issue.entities.add(e1);

    // solve
    SolverFactory<OptaplannerIssue2> solverFactory = SolverFactory.create(new SolverConfig()
        .withEnvironmentMode(EnvironmentMode.FULL_ASSERT).withSolutionClass(OptaplannerIssue2.class)
        .withEntityClasses(IssueEntity.class)
        .withScoreDirectorFactory(
            new ScoreDirectorFactoryConfig().withConstraintProviderClass(OptaplannerIssue2.class))
        .withTerminationConfig(new TerminationConfig().withSecondsSpentLimit(5L)).withPhases(
            new ConstructionHeuristicPhaseConfig()
                .withConstructionHeuristicType(ConstructionHeuristicType.FIRST_FIT),
            new LocalSearchPhaseConfig().withLocalSearchType(LocalSearchType.LATE_ACCEPTANCE)));
    Solver<OptaplannerIssue2> solver = solverFactory.buildSolver();
    solver.solve(issue);
  }
}
```

With the following entity-class:

```java
@PlanningEntity
public class IssueEntity {

  @PlanningVariable(valueRangeProviderRefs = {"valueRange"})
  Integer value;

  public Integer getValue() {
    return value;
  }
}
```

---

In the related thread: [Optaplanner GroupBy with toList not working as expected](https://stackoverflow.com/q/65549360/12704240) the questioner didn't provide all information to commentators trying to help and when I provided reproducer there I got deleted, so I had to ask new question.

Comment: Interesting. How does your ConstraintProvider code look like?

Comment: You are not doing anything wrong, this is a bug. (https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-2305) Thanks for reporting. At the moment, I am not aware of any workarounds, other than to not use collectors that return collections.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The behavior you describe is a bug in OptaPlanner, which we have now fixed. Please upgrade to the next release of OptaPlanner, which at the time of writing this answer will be OptaPlanner 8.2.0.

For details, see [PLANNER-2305](https://issues.redhat.com/browse/PLANNER-2305).

Comment: In 8.2.0 I wasn't able to reproduce this bug - thanks for instant fix.